# All possible non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $225$ and the minimum possible collapsion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

**Exercise :**

> Give all the non isomorphic abelian groups of order $225$ and collapse them in to the minimum possible.

**Attempt :**

We have that the prime factorization of $225$ is :

$$225 = 3^2\cdot5^2$$

This means that all the non isomorphic abelian groups of order $225$ are :

$$\mathbb Z_{3^2} \times \mathbb Z_{5^2} $$

$$\mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{5^2}$$

$$\mathbb Z_{3^2} \times \mathbb Z_{5} \times \mathbb Z_{5}$$

$$\mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{5} \times \mathbb Z_{5}$$

How would one proceed by collapsing (shortening) one of the above expressions to the shortest (minimum) expression ?

Comment: You have to write them as products of quotients by the *invariant factors*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used **Fundamental theorem of abelian groups** .So,after that, the shortening using that $gcd(a,b)=1$ is :

1)$\mathbb Z_{3^2} \times \mathbb Z_{5^2}\cong\mathbb Z_{225}  $

2)$\mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{25}  \cong\mathbb Z_{3}\times \mathbb Z_{75} $

3)$\mathbb Z_{9} \times \mathbb Z_{5} \times \mathbb Z_{5}  \cong\mathbb Z_{45}\times \mathbb Z_{5}$

4)$\mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{5}\times \mathbb Z_{5} \cong\mathbb Z_{15}\times \mathbb Z_{15}$

**Ps: $\mathbb Z_{a} \times \mathbb Z_{b} $**